# can't add simulator to xcode 7.3.1

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

I installed xcode 7.3.1 and started a new project with single page template, but when i try to run it it says that "build only device cant run the application and i should add new device or simulator".

when i go to "window->devices" there is only one device and it mymac system, when i hit + button and add simulator i have ios version 9.3 and after selecting the device type and giving it a name and hitting the create button, nothing happens.

`/Library/Developer` folder dose not exist.

Mac OS X El Capitan 10.11.2

Just to be sure, i uninstalled xcode 7 using cleanmymac3 and restarted system and installed xcode 6.4, it installed successfully and had multiple simulators already defined and a test project successfully run in the simulator. Then i installed xcode 7 witch told me that a older version already exist and if i want to keep them both or replace the older and i choose to replace.Then started a new project with xcode 7 and it was still the same no simulator and i am still not able to add any.

any solution? I am a xcode and MAC noobi ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seems iOS 9.3 simulators are not compatible with AMD cpus :D (go figures) or that my MAC's AMD kernel was not good or ..., anyway the same file installs the components correctly with Intel cpu. poor AMD ...

Comment: You should really lead your questions with something like "I have a Hackintosh with an AMD CPU and a hand-rolled kernel" ;)  Newer versions of Xcode target higher deployment targets which remove support for older hardware.  This allows the compiler to make use of newer CPU extensions.  I suspect your AMD CPU just doesn't meet the requirements for OS X 10.11.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia you are absolutely right, I should have mentioned that :D.

Answer (score 1):

Try to Update your OSX to latest version i.e. 10.11.5  because XCode 7.3.1 requires updates OSX / macos

hop it will help you

Comment: XCode 7.3.1 should work just fine on 10.11.2.  Xcode 8, on the other hand, requires Xcode 10.11.5 or later.